# Analog searchChatsNearby method in MTProto

Tags: telegram, tdlib, mtproto

there is a searchChatsNearby method in TDLib (https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1search_chats_nearby.html), because TDLib uses the MTProto protocol, there should be an analog in the protocol, but I can't find it in the scheme (https://core.telegram.org/schema/mtproto), how to understand what features of the MTProto scheme the searchChatsNearby method is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's contacts.getLocated, which returns both users and groups